# How to specify a Column name (in a where clause) which has a space in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have the below table

```
ID  First Name  Last Name
1   Ruby            Rails 
2   Loop            Western
```

The columns have a space in them and so when I write a query like

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons where [Last Name] = 'Western' ";`

it throws the error

`Error, could not list tables MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Last Name] = 'Western'' at line 1`

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is valid, you would have to use backticks:

```
`Last Name`
```

but if you ask me, don't do this. It's begging for trouble somewhere along the way. Just use an underscore or CamelCase: `LastName`

Comment: This does assume the OP has any control over the schema, but... agreed. +1

Answer (score 4):

You use back-ticks around the column name:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE `Last Name` = 'Western'
```

Note that this is not Standard SQL; neither is the Microsoft notation using square brackets around the name.  The SQL Standard uses 'delimited identifiers' which are enclosed in double quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE "Last Name" = 'Western'
```

Comment: If it's not standard why do you suggest him to use it and not the " " ? I am confused, it's better to use the " " or the ' ' or the ` ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use,

SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE [Last Name] = 'Western'

as alternate in case if you are using the double quotes for wrapping the whole command as a string to pass it on to some function.

For example in pandas:

pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE [Last Name] = 'Western'", con)